# Setting up a pin in NXP LPC1769

Tags: nxp-microcontroller

I only need to modify a source code for just another port/pins.
I have studied with [NXP UM10360](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf) as much as I could.

I have that setup;

Header file used from "CMSIS_CORE_LPC17xx" : **LPC17xx.h**

```
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= 0x2<<14; //P0.7 > SCK1 
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= 0x2<<16; //P0.8 > MISO1 
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= 0x2<<18; //P0.9 > MOSI1
```

and

I want to replace those pins with another (from SSP1 to SSP0).

```
P0.7 will be P0.15
P0.8 will be P0.17
P0.9 will be P0.18
```

And as per the manual, I tried this (Function 10);

```
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 &= ~((0x3 << 31)|(0x3 << 30));//P0.15, SCK0
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= ((0x2 << 31)|(0x2 << 30)); //ENable clock
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~((0x2 << 3)|(0x2 << 2));//P0.17,  MISO0
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~((0x2 << 5)|(0x2 << 4));//P0.18,  MOSI0
```

But, SPI device has stopped after this. The original setup above is working fine and showing me nice SPI signals with Logic Analyzer. But, with that new pins and setup accordingly, I can only get CSN and MISO and SCK only enabled (no pulse) on the Logic Analyzer.

**Just this:**

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
(I am inexperienced with NXP MCU's, please bear with me.)

**Edited:**

For the records, I found it my-self eventually, problem solved;

```
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= 0x2<<30; //SCK0, P0.15 
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= 0x2<<2;  //MISO0, P0.17 
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= 0x2<<4;  //MOSI0, P0.18 
LPC_GPIO0->FIODIR |= (1<<16);   //SSEL/CSN, P0.16
```

Here is the outcome on the Logic Analyzer;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records, I could manage to setup a working solution just by setting up that way;

```
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= 0x2<<30; //SCK0, P0.15 
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= 0x2<<2;  //MISO0, P0.17 
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= 0x2<<4;  //MOSI0, P0.18 
    LPC_GPIO0->FIODIR |= (1<<16);   //SSEL/CSN, P0.16
```